# Placing anchor between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, draw

I'm using `tikzpicture` to draw the next image:

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[anchor=south east] {y};       
        \fill (0.5,0.5)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=north west] {M};
        \fill (5,4)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=north west] {T};
        \fill (6,5)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=north west] {$D_{1}$};
        \fill (4,3)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=north west] {$D_{2}$};
        \draw[thick,->] (0.5,0.5) -- (1,1) node[anchor=north west] {$V_{M}$};
        \draw[thick,->] (6,5) -- (5.5,5.5) node[anchor=north east] {$V_{T}$};
        \draw[thick,->] (4,3) -- (3.5,3.5) node[anchor=north east] {$V_{T}$};
        \draw[dashed,<->] (4,0.5) -- (4,2.9) node[-1cm] {$y_{T_{1}}$};
        \draw[dashed,<->] (5,0.5) -- (5,3.9) node[anchor=south east] {$y_{cent}$};
        \draw[dashed,<->] (6,0.5) -- (6,4.9) node[anchor=south east] {$y_{T_{2}}$};
        \draw [dashed] (0.5,0.5) -- (6,0.5);
        \draw (6.414235,4) arc (0:360:1.414213);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I would like the text of the middle line (`y_{cent}`) to appear where the red circle is and not in the top of the dashed arrow.

Comment: Try `(5,0.5) --node[anchor=west]{$y_{\text{cent}}$} (5,3.9) `.

Comment: See my edited answer below.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I'd draw like this, maybe improved version with better labels positioning.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[anchor=north east] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[anchor=north east] {$y$};       
    \fill (0.5,0.5)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=north] {$M$};
    \fill (5,4)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=west] {$T$};
    \fill (6,5)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=south west] {$D_{1}$};
    \fill (4,3)  circle[radius=2pt]node[anchor=north east] {$D_{2}$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0.5,0.5) -- (1,1) node[anchor=south] {$V_{M}$};
    \draw[thick,->] (6,5) -- (5.5,5.5) node[anchor=south] {$V_{T}$};
    \draw[thick,->] (4,3) -- (3.5,3.5) node[anchor=east] {$V_{T}$};
    \draw[dashed,<->] (4,0.5) -- (4,2.9) node[anchor=south west] {$y_{T_{1}}$};
    \draw[dashed,<->] (5,0.5) --node[anchor=center,fill=white] {$y_{\text{cent}}$} (5,3.9) ;
    \draw[dashed,<->] (6,0.5) -- (6,4.9) node[anchor=east] {$y_{T_{2}}$};
    \draw [dashed] (0.5,0.5) -- (6,0.5);
    \draw (5,4) circle (1.41cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i would draw your image as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
dot/.style = {circle, inner sep=1pt, fill}
                    ]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {x};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[below left] {y};
%
\node[dot, label=below:$M$] at (0.5,0.5)    {};
\node[dot, label=right:$T$] at (5,4)        {};
\node[dot, label=right:$D_{1}$] at (6,5)    {};
\node[dot, label=right:$D_{2}$] at (4,3)    {};
%
\draw[thick,->] (0.5,0.5) -- (1,1) node[right] {$V_{M}$};
\draw[thick,->] (6,5) -- (5.5,5.5) node[above right] {$V_{T}$};
\draw[thick,->] (4,3) -- (3.5,3.5) node[below left] {$V_{T}$};
\draw[dashed,<->] (4,0.5) to ["$y_{T_{1}}^{}$"]     (4,2.9);
\draw[dashed,<->] (5,0.5) to ["$y_\mathrm{cent}$"]  (5,3.9);
\draw[dashed,<->] (6,0.5) to ["$y_{T_{2}}^{}$"]     (6,4.9);
\draw [dashed] (0.5,0.5) -- (6,0.5);
\draw (5,4) circle (1.414213);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```